# Iterating through table rows in nested divs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page that contains a couple of layers of nested div tags.  Within the the 8 or 9 of the divs are tables.  How do I iterate through the divs and pick the specific divs that I want and then iterate through the cells in the table (one row) embedded in each of the divs?  Here is a representative sample of the page that I want to iterate through.

```
<div id="TheHouseDiv" class="catbox_m">
  <div class="Room1Div">
     <table width="900" border="0">
       <tbody>
         <tr>
           <td><a href="/blah/blah1.html">I don't care about this value</a></td>
           <td><a href="/blah/blah2.html">I WANT THIS VALUE 1!</a></td>
           <td><a href="/blah/blah3.html">I WANT THIS VALUE TOO 2!</a></td>
           <td><a href="/blah/blah4.html">Another cell I don't want</a></td>
           <td><a href="/blah/blah5.html">THIS CELL I WANT ALSO</a></td>
         <tr>
       </tbody>
     </table>
     <table width="900" border="0">
       <tbody>
         <tr>
           <td><a href="/blah/blah1.html">Ignore this value in the second table</a></td>
           <td><a href="/blah/blah2.html">I WANT THIS VALUE</a></td>
           <td><a href="/blah/blah3.html">I WANT THIS VALUE TOO</a></td>
           <td><a href="/blah/blah4.html">Ignore this content</a></td>
           <td><a href="/blah/blah5.html">GET THIS CELL VALUE</a></td>
         <tr>
       </tbody>
     </table>
   </div>
   <div class="Room2Div">
     <table width="900" border="0">
       <tbody>
         <tr>
           <td><a href="/blah/blah1.html">I don't care about this value</a></td>
           <td><a href="/blah/blah2.html">I WANT THIS VALUE 1!</a></td>
           <td><a href="/blah/blah3.html">I WANT THIS VALUE TOO 2!</a></td>
           <td><a href="/blah/blah4.html">Another cell I don't want</a></td>
...
```

You get the idea. So there is one table within each div and multiple divs.  There are actually between 8 and 10 divs.  None of the tables or cells have IDs so I need to reference the positionally.  However I don't want all of the cell nor all of the tables.  I only want values from specific cells in each of the tables within each div although I want the same cells from every table.  Would I iterate through this or just reference the specific cells I want and if so, how do I select them?

Comment: I guess this should have been titled "Referencing tables and cells positionally"

Comment: Any feedback to my answer? Doesn't it do what you want?

Answer (score 1):

This gives you all the `td`s which you want. (if you don't understand the selector just post a comment and I will explain it.

```
$("div#TheHouseDiv > div > table td:not(:nth-child(1)):not(:nth-child(4))")
```

e.g. to loop over the `href`s of the `<a>` tags inside these `td`s

```
$("div#TheHouseDiv > div > table td:not(:nth-child(1)):not(:nth-child(4)) a")
    .each(function(i, ele) {
        alert(ele.href);
    }
);
```

e.g. to loop over the text of the `<a>` tags inside these `td`s

```
$("div#TheHouseDiv > div > table td:not(:nth-child(1)):not(:nth-child(4)) a")
    .each(function(i, ele) {
        alert($(ele).text()); //or ele.innerHTML if no nasty is in the <a> tags
    }
);
```

Comment: im not really sure, but i think ">" only works in ie, and :nth-child dont work in some browsers too.

Comment: @TeKapa You are totally wrong. jQuery handles the selector in javascript and isn't constrained to the abilities of the browser. That's why we use a cross-browser library like jQuery, it handles all the quirks of the individual browsers and guarantees that this selector behaves the same in every browser.

Comment: Please remove this comment which is very misleading to an inexperienced reader

Comment: Well done, this helped me quite a lot on a completely different matter :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#TheHouseDiv div').eq(1).find('table').eq(2).find('tr').eq(3).find('td').eq(4).text()
```

A bit verbose, but I believe this retrieves the text of the 4th `<td>` inside the 3rd `<tr>` of the 2nd `<table>` from the first `<div>` contained in `#TheHouseDiv`.

You can also use the shortcut `.find('tr:first')` to match the first one.